# How to run Selenium tests against Internet Explorer under Play?

Tags: selenium, playframework-2.0, fluentlenium

We've got some good selenium tests running against Firefox with Play 2.1

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.0/scala/play/api/test/Helpers

However even though webdriver does support Internet Explorer, i dont see an IE helper.  Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [Fluentlenium documentation](https://github.com/FluentLenium/FluentLenium#customize-fluentlenium), your test class should extend `FluentTest`. You can then simply override the `getDefaultDriver()` method to change the browser:

```
public class IntegrationTest extends FluentTest {

    @Override
    public WebDriver getDefaultDriver(){
        return new InternetExplorerDriver();
    }

}
```

You should be able to return any Selenium WebDriver in this method (only tested with IE and FF).